# Photo slider glitches in mobile when button is added

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, swipe

I am using a swiper API to make a swipeable gallery. I am trying to add a button on the slider card however to do so I must remove an overlay on the card and when I do so the slider glitches and goes crazy. I'm a beginner in code so I apologize if it's a silly issue but I'd appreciate some assistance.

The way i make the button functional is by removing the content: '' from the .gallery-cards class. However when I remove it the slider glitches in the mobile view. the .gallery-cards is only present in the codes JS to make the card swipe. I have added the CSS, JS, and HTML below. Thanks for any suggestions or help

```js
/*=============== SWIPER JS GALLERY ===============*/
let swiperCards = new Swiper(".gallery-cards", {
  loop: true,
  loopedSlides: 5,
  cssMode: true,
  effect: 'fade',
});

let swiperThumbs = new Swiper(".gallery-thumbs", {
  loop: true,
  loopedSlides: 5,
  slidesPerView: 3,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,

  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    type: "fraction",
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
});

swiperThumbs.controller.control = swiperCards;
```

```css
.gallery {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gallery__card {
  position: relative;
  width: 228px;
  height: 288px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery__img,
.gallery__card::after,
.gallery__data {
  position: absolute;
}

.gallery__img {
  inset: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.gallery__button {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 15;
}

.gallery__button:hover {
  background-color: #074bb1;
  color: white;
  transition: .6s;
}

.gallery__button-pink {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 15;
}

.gallery__button-pink:hover {
  background-color: #ff66c4;
  color: white;
  transition: .6s;
}

.gallery__card::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0) 32%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .3) 100%);
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.gallery__data {
  bottom: 1.5rem;
  left: 1.75rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

.gallery__title,
.gallery__subtitle {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.gallery__title {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.gallery__subtitle {
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.gallery__overflow {
  position: relative;
}

.gallery__thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.gallery__thumbnail-img {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Swiper class */

.gallery-cards,
.gallery-thumbs {
  width: 260px;
}

.gallery-cards:hover .gallery__img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.gallery .swiper-wrapper {
  padding: 2.5rem 0;
}

.gallery-thumbs {
  height: 132px;
}


/* Active thumbnail */

.swiper-slide-active .gallery__thumbnail {
  transform: translateY(-1.25rem) scale(1.2);
}


/* Rotate thumbnail */

.swiper-slide-next .gallery__thumbnail {
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}

.swiper-slide-prev .gallery__thumbnail {
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}


/* Sliding numbers */

.swiper-pagination-fraction {
  font-size: .813rem;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: hsl(30, 16%, 50%);
  bottom: 0;
}


/* Arrow buttons */

.swiper-button-next::after,
.swiper-button-prev::after {
  content: '';
}

.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: hsl(30, 8%, 15%);
  top: 5.5rem;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  right: -1.5rem;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  left: -1.5rem;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}


/* Other swiper settings */

.gallery-cards::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.swiper-horizontal.swiper-css-mode>.swiper-wrapper {
  scroll-snap-type: initial;
}


/*=============== BREAKPOINTS ===============*/


/* For small devices */

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .swiper-button-next,
  .swiper-button-prev {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* For medium devices */

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .gallery__card {
    width: 290px;
    height: 370px;
  }
  .gallery__thumbnail {
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
  }
  .gallery-cards,
  .gallery-thumbs {
    width: 290px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide">
  <article class="gallery__card">
    <img src="../assets/img/hfsimageslider.png" alt="image gallery" class="gallery__img">
    <div class="gallery__data">
      <a href="google.com"> <button class="gallery__button">More Info</button></a>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```